# Star rating in the ZOO app doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla1.5

On my website I'm using zoo component. Now on my front-end, I have products with star ratings. But some of the star rating doesn't work. When user rates a product it is suppose to display a number, but it displays this:

`follow">`

This is one of the pages that displays the above error when loaded:
http://www.spiritmotorcycles.co.za/motorcycle-accessories/helmets/spirit-full-face-bike-helmets.

There is also a js file called `rating.js` that I think should be modified but I don't know where to start.

Hope you guys will help or respond soon.

Comment: Since it works on some pages and not others, it may be something more than a simple change in the JS file. I would suggest contacting the support for the component/plugin.

Comment: are you using the commercial version of ZOO?

Comment: @Lodder Yes Lodder it is a commercial version. do you think the commercial version might have an impact

Comment: @UnholyRange I will try to contact the yootheme support thanks a lot for your contribution